# Connecting to multiple database and selecting tables at runtime spring boot java

Tags: postgresql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jdbctemplate

I've a usecase where I need to connect to two different databases(Postgres and Oracle). Postgres is already configured with jpa. I need to add one more databases(Oracle). In the oracle database i need to choose tables at runtime for insertion and deletion(since tables are not fixed). Currently im passing the tables in my properties file as a list

```
oracle:
  deletion:
    table:
    - 
     tableName: user
     primaryKey: userId
     emailField: emailId
     deleteTableName: user_delete
    -
     tableName: customer
     primaryKey: customerId
     emailField: emailAddress
     deleteTableName: customer_delete
```

I've created a bean that reads all these properties and puts them in a list

```
@Bean("oracleTables")
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle.deletion.table")
List<Table> getAllTAbles(){
 return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I have a list of emailAddresses with me. For each of these tables i need to fetch primary key based on emailAddress from parent table(value in tableName) and insert data into corresponding deleteTable(value in deleteTableName). Once that is done i need to delete data from the actual table(value in tableName) based on email address.

I'm planning to loop through the list of tables I have in my bean and perform fetch, insert and delete.

sample snippet

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("oracleTables")
List<Table> tables;

public boolean processDelete(List<String> emails){
 for(Table table:tables){
  //fetch all the primary keys for given emails from main table(value in tableName)
  //insert into corresponding delete table
  //delete from main table
 }
}
```

But the question i have is , should i go with jdbcTemplate or jpaRepository/hibernate. And some help with implementation as well with a small sample/link.

The reason for this question is

1)Tables in my case are not fixed

2)I need transaction management to rollback in case of failure in either fetching or  inserting or deletion.

3)I need to configure two databases

Answer (score 0):

> should i go with jdbcTemplate or jpaRepository/hibernate

Most definitely `JdbcTemplate`. `JPA` does not easily allow dynamic tables.

> I need transaction management to rollback in case of failure in either fetching or inserting or deletion

If you need transactions, you'll also need to define two separate transaction managers:

```
@Bean
public TransactionManager oracleTransactionManager() {
    var result = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    ...
    result.setDataSource(oracleDataSource());
    return result;
}

@Bean
public TransactionManager postgresTransactionManager() {
    ...
}
```

Then, if you want declarative transactions, you need to specify the manager with which to run a given method:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "oracleTransactionManager")
public void doWorkInOracleDb() {
    ...
}
```

> I need to configure two databases

Just configure two separate `DataSource` beans. Of course, you will actually need two separate `JdbcTemplate` beans as well.